# Comparing struct fields using reflect

Tags: go

I am trying to do updates on structs for use in a PUT API. I need to find out if a field in the new struct has a different value as the same field in the old struct. I have never used reflect before, so I am a bit confused. Here is the code I have, I expected it to only print fields that are different, but it prints every field.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Permission struct {
    User       int    `json:"user" db:"user"`
    ObjectId   int    `json:"object_id" db:"object_id"`
    ObjectType string `json:"object_type" db:"object_type"`
    Permission string `json:"codename" db:"codename"`
}

func main() {
    old := Permission{1, 1, "site", "view_site"}
    new := Permission{1, 2, "site", "edit_site"}
    v1 := reflect.ValueOf(old)
    v2 := reflect.ValueOf(new)
    t := reflect.TypeOf(old)
    for i := 0; i < v1.NumField(); i++ {
        if v2.Field(i) != v1.Field(i) {
            fmt.Printf("%v ", t.Field(i).Name)
            fmt.Printf("old: %v ", v1.Field(i))
            fmt.Printf("new: %v ", v2.Field(i))
            fmt.Println("")
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the reason for this is that each `Value` is a different struct and so they are not equal, but I cannot seem to figure out how to actually do what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind the difference between your reflection values and the values of the underlying struct's fields. This line:

```
v2.Field(i) != v1.Field(i)
```

Compares the reflected field of one struct to the reflected field of another. *Not* the field *values*, but the *reflection of the fields themselves*. To get the values, you'd need to use `Field(i).Interface()`, which would return the field's value as an `interface{}`.

You can see a working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/0tAkjGTpCeu

Comment: Ha! I knew I was missing something simple. How can I handle a situation where my struct has other structs as members? (in particular Null types from database/sql)

Comment: It's reflection, so it's complicated. If you're looking for specific handling for certain types, you could use type assertion or type switching on the value returned from `Interface()`. For more generic handling, you can check the field's `Kind()` and if it's a struct, handle it recursively.

Comment: As with anything involving reflection, I'd strongly suggest finding an alternative design. Reflection should be a solution of last resort.

Comment: There seems to be an awful lot of reflect usage in the base library, both encoding and database packages seem to use reflect a lot for purposes similar to the one I have above. I am not sure I can come up with a better design provided my problem domain involves both serialization and reading from database.

Comment: There's not much reflection usage outside of encoding and database packages. Reflection code is complicated, slow, fragile, and difficult to read. Also remember that the standard library is forced to use reflection because it has to support whatever a developer might need it for; your own code can actually be type-safe because you're not writing the standard library.

Comment: That is true. So, I have a bunch of struct types that map to objects in my architecture. At some point, I need to deserialize incoming data into a struct, pull an existing record, compare the two and build and execute a minimal required SQL update query. I could define a compare method for each struct type that would literally go through every field comparing their values, but that seems cumbersome, especially for bigger structs. So I figured I could do the same thing in a more generic fashion using reflect. Could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Given that use case I'd say it's a toss-up between using reflection, and writing a helper to use with `go generate` to generate static-typed code for each type. If performance is of any concern, the latter is probably preferable, but YMMV.

Comment: I wouldn't say "it doesn't matter" since it's not running in parallel with the database access. So while it's faster than the DB access, it's still adding to that time, and cumulatively can make a difference - and unlike the DB access, its performance is actually under your control. As someone who is in fact well-versed in Go, reflection code is still harder to read and reason about than normal, type-safe Go code. And it can certainly be fragile depending on how it is written because it must handle many possible types with no foreknowledge.